# Why ingress "servicePort" can be "port" and "targetPort" of service?

Tags: kubernetes

Today I confronted with a misunderstanding about `servicePort`.

I expected that service can be linked with ingress specifying only `servicePort: 80`, but both `servicePort: 80` and `servicePort: 8080` works.

Can someone help me to understand why both ports `port` and `targetPort` are exposed by Service, not only `port`?

*Service (app)*

```
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

*Ingress (ingress-nginx)*

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 18):

As I understand,

Each Pod in the cluster has an endpoint which is the **IP** and **targetPort** of Pod.

You can list the endpoints with the following commands.

```
kubectl get endpoints
```

Now If you use service to expose your pod then they have **cluster IP** and **Service Port**.

`kubectl get services`

Now you can write the ingress rules to expose your pod via **endpoints** or **cluster ip**. However, There are only a few Ingress-Controller which can do this task. for example **nginx-ingress-controller**.

Why do you want to use **endpoints** instead of **cluster-ip or Service** ?

> The NGINX ingress controller does not use Services to route traffic to the pods. Instead it uses the Endpoints API in order to bypass kube-proxy to allow NGINX features like session affinity and custom load balancing algorithms. It also removes some overhead, such as conntrack entries for iptables DNAT.

Here is the link for further research [Why endpoints and not services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#why-endpoints-and-not-services)

Comment: Very thanks for explanations! "Why endpoints and not services" is that I'm missing.

Comment: Hi, your welcome. By the way, When you create pod, then you get endpoints. When you create service then you get cluster IP. It's quite abstract. So the purpose of using endpoints is session stickiness. For example, If you access a pod in the first time. in order to have session stickiness, you need to use endpoints. so next time you will access the same pod.